# What are the alternatives to "Forward with Masking" on the DNS for my home server?

Tags: django, web, dns

I am running a server using Django on an AWS instance with a public ip xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. I then registered a domain name through GoDaddy at mydomain.com that redirects users to the ip of my server. Users who type mydomain.com/content/ into their browser are directed to the correct page, but now see xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/content in the url bar, instead of mydomain.com/content/. I am currently dealing with this problem by choosing a "Forward with Masking" setting through GoDaddy, but it is redirecting mydomain.com/content/ to mydomain.com/, and seems generally less reliable than the functionality I see when I use other sites. What are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently seem to use feature often referred as URL forwarding. You don't need it, simply switch URL forwarding off. What you do want is a **DNS record** of the following form:

```
mydomain.com A xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Comment: Any insight as to where I should put this? I did a fair amount of googling but it isn't obvious.

Comment: @user2237635 DNS settings, DNS records, DNS. Somewhere in the GoDaddy control panel. Can't be more specific - I never used GoDaddy. Ask their support maybe

Comment: Yea, this is the conclusion I had come to. Just wanted to make sure and ask the question in case anyone else had the same issue.